# Does anyone else not enjoy this 'Required 15 Reputation' to vote situation?

Tags: discussion, voting

I know, it's most likely the reason stackexchange has become so popular, by forcing people to actually contribute.

But as a full-time lurker, and long time user (only recently signed up), it kind of bums me out that I don't get to give credit where credit is due.

I don't generally ask questions because I always find a related question before I get myself into the situation where I need to ask and I don't like to answer questions myself as I don't consider myself experienced enough to be contributing effectively.

Hopefully the first response to this post is a quick solution to getting 15 reputation points that I haven't seen, and I can just quickly delete this useless question, or maybe a concise paragraph explaining why my question is redundant and that I should go back to my lurky shadows of which I came from.

All I want to do, is give credit to helpful comments/questions.

Comment: First of all, this isn't Stack Overflow ;) And, for future reference, questions about the site itself should be posted here on Meta, not on the main site.

Comment: I agree with @Yannis Rizos. Are you really complaining that 15 reputation points sets the bar too high?

Comment: one logical point, if you don't find yourself *qualified* to answer questions, what makes your opinions on the correct answers/comments qualified either. just pointing out that doesn't make any sense either. **Just start participating and you will be at 5 digits reputation soon enough!**

Comment: @YannisRizos be nice 1 rep users can't post in meta.

Answer (score 8):

> Hopefully the first response to this post is a quick solution to getting 15 reputation points that I haven't seen

All you need is 8 good edits! While under 2,000 reputation points, you gain 2 points for each edit you make, and with just 8 good edits you'll get the required reputation to up vote (plus 1 ;). There's a small catch, though, your edits must be approved by higher rep members, so don't just do minor edits in hopes of getting some cheap rep, or they'll be outright rejected.

If you decide to start editing, scout for questions and answers with multiple problems, grammatical, syntactical or whatever else, and try your best to fix them, without changing the original intent of the post. Check out the [edit privilege page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) for a summary of what a good edit makes.

Comment: Or one good question, one good answer, etc. 15 rep isn't that hard to get.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you dislike our current situation, but the '15 rep requirement' has it's benefits, which hugely outweigh the disadvantages.

The rule is derived from the initial ideas that are the basis of all StackExchange sites: You need to earn trust, before you are allowed to vote. That ideas has been proven to work very well; It keeps out a big amount of people who would otherwise abuse their privileges, thus affecting the sites' usefulness very badly.

I think it is great that you want to give credit where it is due - in fact, I think that this is exactly the kind of attitude SE needs! As others have pointed out, there are several ways of gaining 15 rep points, so I suggest you *go for it!* And once you have enough rep, you can still accept answers on all the questions you asked before.

Comment: I think it's also one method used to discourage users from creating multiple accounts to vote up everything their main account does.

Answer (score -2):

Participe to any of the exchange site, join another one with same profile : kabam, you're awarded 100 points, so I had fully forgotten about this "15 points" rule.

```
+100    08:36   assoc   Association Bonus
```

Comment: You need to reach 200 reputation on any site before you get the +100 bonus on other sites.

Comment: Ooops, so long ago I had forgotten :-)